# How to Register Generic Interface to Generic Implementation

Tags: generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container, munq

In Unity, I'm able to easily map a generic interface to a generic implementation, such that for all ISomething, I can map SomethingImpl with a single registration.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
//Map all generic repositories to their concrete generic implementations.
container.RegisterType(
                       typeof(IRepository<,>), 
                       typeof(Repository<,>)
                      ); 
var EmployeeRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<Employee, int>>();
```

How would the same be accomplished in Munq?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're out of luck. You have two options:

1. Register all types explicitly:

   ```cs
   container.Register<IRepository<int, User>, Repository<int, User>>();
   container.Register<IRepository<Guid, Order>, Repository<Guid, Order>>();
   container.Register<IRepository<long, OrderLine>, Repository<long, OrderLine>>();
   // etc
   ```

   you can always make a convenient helper method to lessen the pain a bit:

   ```cs
   public static void RegisterRepository<TKey, TEntity>(
       this Container container)
   {
       container.Register<IRepository<TKey, TEntity>, Repository<TKey, TEntity>();
   }

   container.RegisterRepository<int, User>>();
   container.RegisterRepository<Guid, Order>>();
   container.RegisterRepository<long, OrderLine>>();
   // etc
   ```
2. Switch to a different container that has built-in support for open generics. These are the containers I know of that have support for this: Autofac, StructureMap, Unity, Castle Windsor, Ninject, and Simple Injector.

Comment: You can indeed register open generics with Unity, but using a different syntax, as shown in my answer. You don't have the syntactic sugar, but you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can register open generics with Unity like this:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IOpenGeneric<>), typeof(OpenGeneric<>));
```

Then you can resolve them like this:

```
IOpenGeneric<MyClass> value = container.Resolve<IOpenGeneric<MyClass>>();
```

What you cannot do is to use which would be the "obvious" syntax:

```
container.RegisterType<IOpenGeneric<T>,OpenGeneric<T>>() // SYNTAX ERROR!!
```